# MX Notify - Freemember - Custom Profile_data

Tags: member-management

I've got this bit of code where I'm trying to get member custom field information. when I use member_id="41" nothing is rendered. Anyone know why?

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="41"}
<p>{given_name} {family_name}
  {if company_name != ""}<br />{company_name}{/if}</p>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>{bbr-mls-common-location}</h4>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="event_locales" search:city_name="{locale_name}" limit="1"}

      <p>{venue_address}<br /><a href="{venue_website}" target="_blank">{venue_website}</a></p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>{bbr-mls-common-session}</h4>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="locale_slots" entry_id="{locale_slot}" limit="1"}
    <p>
      {if language_code == "en"}
        {start_date_time format="%F %j"}
      {if:else}
        {start_date_time format="%j"} au {end_date_time format="%j"}
        {if '{start_date_time format="%F"}' == "September"} septembre {/if}
        {if '{start_date_time format="%F"}' == "October"} octobre {/if}
        {if '{start_date_time format="%F"}' == "November"} novembre {/if}
        {if '{start_date_time format="%F"}' == "December"} decembre {/if}
      {/if}
      <br />
      {start_date_time format="%g:%i%a"} - {end_date_time format="%g:%i%a"}
    </p>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  </div>
</div>
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happens because Freemember save custom fields data *after* member_register hook is executed. So at the moment when NC parsed template is no custom field data in DB. As temporary solution possible to use plugin which will take this data from _POST (like [GET_POST_Var](https://bitbucket.org/WTSnet/get_post_var/src/2c070a7d934c/pi.get_post_var.php) plugin).

New versions of NC which I'll release this week, have FreeMembers triggers.

Comment: Just stumbled across this thread. Any update on this? I am using Freemember as a registration utility and when I try to trigger a notification email to admins with their custom fields, the fields are sent empty.